# Regression loss function to yield high correlation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, correlation, loss-functions, mse

I am using a neural network to predict a target. Currently, my loss is the mean squared error. I am not interested in the absolute values of my predictions, thus I evaluate the predictions using the Pearson correlation coefficient instead of the MSE.

I have the intuition that I can improve the Pearson by optimizing it more directly.
Additionally, I found [in this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228373/use-pearsons-correlation-coefficient-as-optimization-objective-in-machine-learn) that "Maximizing correlation is useful when the output is highly noisy", which is definitely the case for my data.

Is there something similar to the [siamese neural network/Triplett loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_loss) approach which is as far as I know only used for classification/distinction?

Is it reasonable to just use the Pearson correlation as a loss function? I could not find much about this in the literature, apart from some [comments on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301659/mse-as-a-proxy-to-pearsons-correlation-in-regression-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearson correlation as a loss function presents some problems. In particular, $\text{corr}(y, \hat y)=\text{corr}(y,a+b\hat y)$ for any real $a$ and positive $b$, so $y=(1,2,3)$ and $\hat y=(105, 205, 305)$ have perfect correlation, yet the predictions are terrible.

If you are in a situation where this is acceptable, perhaps Pearson correlation could work for you, but you should be aware of this issue.

The comment in one of your links that $R^2$, for the definition given below, is not correct. Such an equation absolutely catches the poor quality of the above predictions $\hat y$ of $y$. Please see my simulations [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/584562/247274), but it makes sense. The below formula is just a monotonic transformation of the MSE.

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up using an approximation of the rank metric NDCG as a loss function, since, really, what I was interested in was ranking :)